# Why watch time different in Youtube Analytics and Monetization page?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, youtube-monetization

Recently my Youtube channel crossed 4k hour watch time in the last 365 days. I have 1301 subscribers and 4.4k hour watch time. Please see the attached image.

[image]

So, as per Youtube rules I can apply for monetization now. But in the monetization page, the subscriber count is 1290 and watch time is just 1661 hour. Why?

[image]

I waited 2 days thinking that it may take some time to update their databases, but nothing has changed. Why is there such a difference in Analytics and Monetization pages?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had a sudden spike in traffic, maybe from one or two videos. A possible cause is that in those high volume of traffic videos YouTube didn't consider it acceptable for monetization like maybe a copyright strike or something. Or maybe because it is so sudden in the chart YouTube is taking longer to process it. I'm not exactly 100% sure what it is without more context, but I'm sure with time and your channel growing it will eventually show monetization. But remember that if you are just doing YouTube for the monetization, that it probably won't get big anyways. You have to actually enjoy it, at least a little if you want it to grow big in my opinion.